# Test if all items in list are completed before a certain item

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of stages, each have `Id`, `StageNumber` (i.e. index), `Name` and a `Progress object` that contains a bool field called `IsCompleted`.

How can I test if all items before `my current stage` (obj that I will pass into a method) are complete? I have the following code but I am getting false returned, I have checked out my list and the stage 0 is checked as `completed`

```
var indexToTest = mystage.StageNumber; //1 in this instance, as 0 is always true

Assert.IsTrue(progress.Stages.All(stage => stage.StageNumber < indexToTest && stage.Progress.IsCompleted));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's going to fail as soon as it finds any stage with an index greater than or equal to yours. I suspect you want:

```
Assert.IsTrue(progress.Stages.TakeWhile(stage => stage.StageNumber < indexToTest)
                             .All(stage => stage.Progress.IsCompleted));
```

That's assuming the stages are in order. If they're not, you really want to test that every stage is *either* at/after your index to test *or* it's completed:

```
Assert.IsTrue(progress.Stages.All(stage => stage.StageNumber >= indexToTest
                                           || stage.Progress.IsCompleted));
```

EDIT: If it helps you to think about it, here's an alternative:

```
Assert.IsFalse(progress.Stages.Any(stage => stage.StageNumber < indexToTest
                                            && !stage.Progress.IsCompleted));
```

This says "there shouldn't be any stages before `indexToTest` which *aren't* completed".

Comment: I have sorted my list by the index (stage number), and it still fails i.e orderby StageNumber, the list seems as though the objects are coming out as 0,1,2 really weird

Comment: @Haroon: Do you mean it still fails with *your* code, or with both of *my* options? If my suggestions are failing, there's something else wrong and you should post a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: No it failed with my code - I did the sort + what I wrote above, just going to test your suggestion...

Comment: @Haroon: I've explained why it fails with your original code - it finds an item (the second one) where `stage.StageNumber` *isn't* less than `indexToTest`.

Comment: thanks, just to make this clear to myself. Firsly order the list, then do a TakeWhile - this will take all items from my list that are less than my index, then I will check if those items are completed using .All extension method with my condition

Comment: @Haroon: Yes, that's how the first version works - but the second version doesn't require ordering in the first place, so that may be a better approach.